# Can't find COFF file header in hex editor

Tags: winapi, hex, portable-executable

In the offset "0x3c" (from win32 docs) is the location of the signature "PE\0\0" therefore the Machine type must be next to it.

However in the next 2 hex values (since it said size 2) "4C 01" didn't match in the win32 docs

[view in hex editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqZd5.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [IMAGE_FILE_HEADER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-image_file_header) follows the signature `PE\0\0`. The first `WORD` does in fact hold the target `Machine`. `IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386` has the value `0x014c` (which is stored as `4C 01` in little-endian byte order). That coincides with your observations.

The hex dump indicates an image with x86 object code, and agrees with the informal [PE Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format) specification.